# MySQL rename column

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a homework question I had but I just wasn't sure if I got the correct answer. The question was:

Write a SQL statement to count the number of rows in the relation R(A, B, C) and rename the result column as num

My answer:

```
COUNT(*) AS num
```

Is this correct or do I have to use ALTER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you've got it right. `ALTER`is used to change existing database objects (for example the name of a table - it's a data definition statement (DDL)). Using `AS`gives your result an alias, so this statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM TABLE_A
```

would count the number of rows in the table and output the result in a column named `num`. Note that the count is not for distinct rows unless you specify it, or use a`group by`clause, so if there are duplicate rows they would all get counted.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you got the right answer. Using alias is way in renaming fieldname in using SQL Statement.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM TABLE
```

Comment: `ALTER`is a SQL statement though, just not a DML statement, but rather a DDL.